# How to convert Drools rule drl to Drools Workflow bpmn

Tags: drools, bpmn

I am new user to Drools rule language.
Can I convert Drools rule file .drl to Drools workflow diagram .bpmn? Here is some pieces of rule for my drools rule file.

```
rule "classNameDeclaration"

when
     $st : SyntaxTree( status == SyntaxTree.CLASS_DECLARE )
then

    TypeDeclaration type=AST2Android.classNameDeclaration($st.getClassName());

    $st.setStatus(SyntaxTree.VARIABLE_DECLARE);
    $st.setType(type);
    update($st);
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. 
Drools is a [production rule framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_system_(computer_science)) and bmpn is a way to express a [business process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_process_management). Even when these 2 technologies can be used together (and sometimes for similar purposes), that doesn't mean that you can translate from one to the other.

Hope it helps,

Comment: thanks, it helps me. May I ask one more pls. Can drools rule convert to decision table? How do can I express drools rule in simple form? Because I have to present more than 50 rules in details.